# How to connect to a local database from server

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

trying to access to an external database in local via my server, I executed this code server side:

```
console.log('MONGODB_URI_LOCAL::', config.MONGODB_URI_LOCAL)

const mongooseLocal = require('mongoose');
const connectionOptions = { useCreateIndex: true, useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true, useFindAndModify: false };
const conn = mongooseLocal.createConnection(config.MONGODB_URI_LOCAL, connectionOptions);
conn.on("error", console.error.bind(console, "connection error: "));
conn.once("open", async () => {
  console.log("Connected successfully");
});
```

And I get this error:

> MongoError: Authentication failed

here is the format of the URI:

```
config.MONGODB_URI_LOCAL = mongodb://user_name:my_password@localhost:27017/my_db_name
```

This is the first time I try to connect to a local database so:

Is this possible to connect to a local database from server and read or write data ?

If yes How can I fix this issue ?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63754742/authentication-failure-while-trying-to-save-to-mongodb/63755470#63755470

Answer (score 1):

Here's an approach that you can use.
This approach enables you to export your connection logic to other parts of your code.

```js
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const connect = async (callback) => {
    try{
        const connectionOptions = { 
            useCreateIndex: true, 
            useNewUrlParser: true, 
            useUnifiedTopology: true, 
            useFindAndModify: false 
        };
        await mongoose.connect(config.MONGODB_URI_LOCAL, connectionOptions)

        // On successful connection you can call your callback function
        callback()
    }catch(err){
        console.log(err)
        process.exit(1)
    }
}

connect()
```